# How to create ThreadPool that executes random task from queue

Tags: java, concurrency, queue, threadpool

ThreadPool's uses BlockingQueue to store tasks in queue.

I want executor that takes random task from queue. So first task and last task in queue have equal chances to be taken from.

Is that possible to do?

Comment: random? I sincerely doubt that's a good idea, since a Queue works on a FIFO-principle (First In, First Out). Though there are always alternatives. Just think about a Priority queue. Granted, it's not random, it doesn't follow the FIFO order, it does, however, follows a certain order. You might be able to implement it, but there are no doubt quite some vital possible side-effects easy to loose out of sight

Comment: Yes, possible you need to write your own implementation of `BlockingQueue`, however, I would not recommend such implementation as it directly contradicts the principal of a Queue  .

Comment: Use a `PriorityBlockingQueue` and randomly assign a priority value when and entry is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is technically possible to implement a thread pool which chooses the next task randomly.  You can instantiate `ThreadPool` with a caller-supplied queue.

While it seems strange (even dangerous or subversive!) to some people<sup>1</sup>, a `Queue` is not necessarily FIFO.  Indeed the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.htmlhttps://www.standard.co.uk/lifestyle/london-life/british-people-display-amazing-queuing-etiquette-without-being-told-a3528366.html) for `Queue` states:

> Queues typically, **but do not necessarily**, order elements in a FIFO (first-in-first-out) manner.

So all you need to do to implement random thread pool behavior is to implement your own `BlockingQueue` class with a `take()` that selects the element randomly.

Alternatively, @Ben Manes' idea is use a `PriorityBlockingQueue` and assign random priorities.  (This is simpler, but there is an overhead in keeping the queue *heapified*: `O(1)` on average, but `O(logN)` in the worst case.)

---

<sup>1 - Actually, in the real world queues are largely a social convention.  Some cultures apparently don't follow this convention; e.g. https://www.thelocal.it/20150410/my-italian-habits-that-foreigners-just-dont-get.  By contrast: https://www.standard.co.uk/lifestyle/london-life/british-people-display-amazing-queuing-etiquette-without-being-told-a3528366.html</sup>